# Set menu item string when debugging UIWebView in Safari

Tags: uiwebview, safari

I'm building an iOS app that uses multiple instances of `UIWebView`. When I use Safari to debug the UIWebViews the menu items in the "Develop" menu of Safari are titled "blank",

[image: "blank" menu items]

so it is difficult to distinguish them. I noticed that when Mobile Safari is the active app the menu item has the form "website host - page"

[image: descriptive menu items],

but when I use `UIWebView` my app is generating the HTML dynamically so there is no URL to base the name on. I've tested and the menu text is not set when the HTML title is set. <del>It is also not set by setting the base URL of the `UIWebView`.</del> Does anyone know if it is possible to set the menu text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my test case was wrong and it is possible to set the menu item by setting the base URL of the `UIWebView`. For example:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:[self html] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]];
```

This works, but it isn't particularly elegant. Are there alternative ways to set the menu item?